# Function for logic: Geocoding script for county selection

Tags: r, function, dplyr, geocoding

I wrote following script to get the corresponding or best county match for a given input string of a city, like "New York, NY". The desired logic is commented inline. I tried my best and made the code reproducible. You can just change the corresponding `dat` and `place` input (2.2.1) to see the way it works.

```
# Load Packages
library(acs)
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
data(fips_codes)

# 1. Select Data

dat = geo.lookup(state = "NY", place = "New York")
#dat = geo.lookup(state = "TX", place = "Dallas")
#dat = geo.lookup(state = "OR", place = "Portland")
#dat = geo.lookup(state = "NY", place = "Manhattan")
#dat = geo.lookup(state = "NY", place = "Queens")
print(dat)

dat = na.omit(dat) # remove first row that is only contains state information and NA

# 2. Check whether county.name has multiple counties, separated by comma
cvals <- dat %>% filter(str_detect(county.name, ","), row_number() == 2L)
nrow(cvals)

# 2.1 If nrow(cvals) = 0, take first row
dat[1,]

# 2.2 If nrow(cvals) > 0, do split string and unnest
unbundle <- dat %>% 
  group_by(state.name, place.name) %>% 
  mutate(county.name = strsplit(county.name, ", ")) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  na.omit()
unbundle

# 2.2.1 If "place =" input matches a county.name in unbundle, select that row
check <- unbundle %>% filter(str_detect(county.name, "New York"))
nrow(check)
#select that row
select <- unbundle %>% filter(str_detect(county.name, "New York"))

# 2.2.2 Otherwise, if there is no match, i.e. nrow(select) = 0, take first row from unbundle by default
unbundle[1,]

# 3.1 Merge countyfips from fips_codes into selected table (For New York, the final output of 2.2.1 would have been selected)
colnames(fips_codes) = c("state.abb", "statefips", "state.name", "countyfips", "county.name")
select %>% left_join(fips_codes, by = c("state.name", "county.name"))
```

I wonder how this function can be written, so that an input, like "Portland, OR", "Queens, NY", or anything above would work. Maybe, there's also a smarter way to write the whole script. As I'm learning dplyr, dlplyr solutions are preferred.

Thanks!

Solution (updated):

```
library(acs)
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
data(fips_codes)
colnames(fips_codes) = c("state.abb", "statefips", "state.name", "countyfips", "county.name")

    FUN <- function(x) {
      Place <- strsplit(x, ", ")[[1]][1]
      State <- strsplit(x, ", ")[[1]][2]
      dat = geo.lookup(state = State, place = Place)
      dat = na.omit(dat)

      # 1 Check whether county.name has multiple counties
      cvals <- dat %>% filter(str_detect(county.name, ","))

      # 2 If not, i.e. cvals == 0, take first row of output
      if(nrow(cvals[2,]) == 0) {
        output <- dat[1,]
      }

      # 3 If yes, i.e. cvals > 0, unbundle code and proceed
      else {
        unbundle <- dat %>% 
          group_by(state.name, place.name) %>% 
          mutate(county.name = strsplit(county.name, ", ")) %>% 
          unnest %>%
          na.omit()

        # 3.1 If "Place" matches one of county.name values, take that row
        check <- unbundle %>% filter(str_detect(county.name, Place))
        nrow(check)

        if (nrow(check) > 0) {
        output <- check[1,]
      } 
        # 3.2 Otherwise, if no match, nrow(check) = 0, take first row from unbundle by default
        output <- unbundle[1,]
      }
    # Join county data with fips code table
      output <- output %>% left_join(fips_codes, by = c("state.name", "county.name"))
      print(output)
    }

    FUN("New York, NY")
    FUN("Portland, OR")
    FUN("Manhattan, NY")
    FUN("Cambridge, MA")
```

Comment: Do you mean all the code above should be wrapped in a function and should be able to operate on the input `"Portland, OR"`?

Comment: If you look at the output of the different dat inputs, you will see that it can have only one county, which is fine, but somestimes also multiple counties, where one of those matches the city name. So I need this testing procedure to make sure it selects the best "county" for a given input like "Portland, OR", "Dallas, TX", "New York, NY", ... So the ideal function is the one that works roughly like above, or at least produces the right result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Q is not really clear, but just use the `acs` data frame directly:

```
library(acs)
library(tidyverse)

place_to_county <- function(place, state = NULL) {

  if (is.null(state)) {

    x <- trimws(strsplit(place, ",", 2)[[1]])

    place <- x[1]
    state <- x[2]

  }

  tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>%
    filter(grepl(place, PLACENAME, ignore.case=TRUE) & STATE == state) %>%
    separate_rows(COUNTY, sep=", ") %>%
    head(1) %>%
    setNames(tolower(colnames(.)))

}
```

Some examples:

```
place_to_county("New York", "NY")
## # A tibble: 1 x 7
##   state statefp placefp     placename               type funcstat       county
##   <chr>   <int>   <int>         <chr>              <chr>    <chr>        <chr>
## 1    NY      36   51000 New York city Incorporated Place        A Bronx County

place_to_county("New York, NY")
## # A tibble: 1 x 7
##   state statefp placefp     placename               type funcstat       county
##   <chr>   <int>   <int>         <chr>              <chr>    <chr>        <chr>
## 1    NY      36   51000 New York city Incorporated Place        A Bronx County

place_to_county("Queens", "NY")
## # A tibble: 1 x 7
##   state statefp placefp      placename               type funcstat        county
##   <chr>   <int>   <int>          <chr>              <chr>    <chr>         <chr>
## 1    NY      36   60323 Queens borough County Subdivision        G Queens County

place_to_county("Queens, NY")
## # A tibble: 1 x 7
##   state statefp placefp      placename               type funcstat        county
##   <chr>   <int>   <int>          <chr>              <chr>    <chr>         <chr>
## 1    NY      36   60323 Queens borough County Subdivision        G Queens County

place_to_county("Berwick", "ME")
## # A tibble: 1 x 7
##   state statefp placefp   placename                    type funcstat      county
##   <chr>   <int>   <int>       <chr>                   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>
## 1    ME      23    4685 Berwick CDP Census Designated Place        S York County

place_to_county("Berwick, ME")
## # A tibble: 1 x 7
##   state statefp placefp   placename                    type funcstat      county
##   <chr>   <int>   <int>       <chr>                   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>
## 1    ME      23    4685 Berwick CDP Census Designated Place        S York County

place_to_county("Manhattan", "NY")
## # A tibble: 1 x 7
##   state statefp placefp         placename               type funcstat          county
##   <chr>   <int>   <int>             <chr>              <chr>    <chr>           <chr>
## 1    NY      36   44919 Manhattan borough County Subdivision        G New York County

place_to_county("Manhattan, NY")
## # A tibble: 1 x 7
##   state statefp placefp         placename               type funcstat          county
##   <chr>   <int>   <int>             <chr>              <chr>    <chr>           <chr>
## 1    NY      36   44919 Manhattan borough County Subdivision        G New York County
```

As you can see, that works if the parameters are specified separately or as an "x, y" string.

This version is a bit more robust:

```
place_to_county <- function(place, state = NULL) {

  if (is.null(state)) {

    x <- trimws(strsplit(place, ",", 2)[[1]])

    place <- x[1]
    state <- x[2]

  }

  tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>% 
    filter(grepl(place, PLACENAME, ignore.case=TRUE) & STATE == state) -> xdf

  if (nrow(xdf) > 0) {
    separate_rows(xdf, COUNTY, sep=", ") %>%
    head(1) %>%
    setNames(tolower(colnames(.)))
  } else {
    NULL
  }

}
```

as it gracefully handles complete misses.

UPDATE to address the comment (I'll use the simplified version of the code):

```
tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>%
  filter(grepl(place, PLACENAME, ignore.case=TRUE) & STATE == state) %>%
  separate_rows(COUNTY, sep=", ") %>%
  head(1) %>%
  setNames(tolower(colnames(.)))
```

Whereas:

- `%>%` the pipe symbol seen in tidyverse/dplyr code. It (oversimplifying) avoids using temporary variables assignments
- `tbl_df(…)` (again, oversimplifying) just ensures the output is more human-readable (it tags the data frame with additional classes)
- `filter(…)` does the work you want. the `grepl()` case-insensitive searches for the place and then takes those matches and further refines by state. This is a "dumb" way to do it since it catches the place name anywhere in the string. There are smarter ways, but this should work pretty well.
- `separate_rows(…)` will take the entries in `fips.place` that have more than one county in them and make a separate row for each county.
- `head(1)` naively takes the first match
- `setNames(…)` makes lower-case column names as the ones in `fips.place` are (ugh) all UPPER_CASE

PENULTIMATE UPDATE

This merges the `tigris` `place_name` data:

```
place_to_county <- function(place, state = NULL) {

  if (is.null(state)) {

    x <- trimws(strsplit(place, ",", 2)[[1]])

    place <- x[1]
    state <- x[2]

  }

  tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>%
    filter(grepl(place, PLACENAME, ignore.case=TRUE) & STATE == state) -> xdf

  if (nrow(xdf) > 0) {
    separate_rows(xdf, COUNTY, sep=", ") %>%
      head(1) %>%
      setNames(tolower(colnames(.))) %>% 
      left_join(tigris::fips_codes, by=c("county", "state"))
  } else {
    NULL
  }

}
```

FINAL UPDATE (for real):

This was a pretty simple addition. I'm not going to refine this further. You won't get better at coding in R w/o some experimentation on your own.

```
place_to_county <- function(place, state = NULL) {

  if (is.null(state)) {

    x <- trimws(strsplit(place, ",", 2)[[1]])

    place <- x[1]
    state <- x[2]

  }

  tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>%
    filter(grepl(place, PLACENAME, ignore.case=TRUE) & STATE == state) -> xdf

  if (nrow(xdf) > 0) {
    separate_rows(xdf, COUNTY, sep=", ") %>%
      head(1) %>%
      setNames(tolower(colnames(.))) %>% 
      left_join(tigris::fips_codes, by=c("county", "state"))
  } else {
    data_frame(
      state = state, 
      statefp = NA, 
      placefp = NA, 
      placename = place, 
      type = NA, 
      funcstat = NA, 
      county = NA, 
      state_code = NA, 
      state_name = NA,
      county_code = NA
    )
  }

}
```

Any other features/changes are up to you.

Comment: could you explain "  tbl_df(acs::fips.place) ... separate_rows(xdf, COUNTY, sep=", ") %>%" ?

Comment: Just discovered: One point is missing: How can you match that table with the county.fips? Because that data is in `data(fips_codes)`

Comment: Thanks for the very good code comment! If we only get the last point resolved, it would be awesome!

Comment: "This is a "dumb" way to do it since it catches the place name anywhere in the string. There are smarter ways, but this should work pretty well." -> It should only match with the county.name, if possible?

Comment: Compare the logic of the `geo.lookup()` function — https://github.com/cran/acs/blob/master/R/acs.R#L389-L523 — with this and make any filtering logic changes you like.

Comment: When merging the geo lookups with my original data table, I realized that is has less rows. I assume the "NULL" in the code prevents that it writes NA rows where not any information was available. Is there a way to get NA rows?

Comment: On your previous answer: I really try hard to understand it but honestly, after three days of trying to understand different packages and syntax, my head is a bit of smashed pumpkin. I know that I need to re-write the `filter(grepl(...` so that is does look for a string match between `place` and -as I see the code- `county=`. But how exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your great help!